# bash script to start and stop a service on Linux Mint is failing

Tags: bash

I recently switched to Linux and have no idea of bash scripting. What I require is a script that can check if a service is stopped and start the service if yes, otherwise it should stop the service. It's basically to start and stop mysql and apache2 which I disabled to run at startup. So when required, we just run the script to start the services and to stop services we again run the script. I tried something that is obviously not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
servicex=mysql

if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $servicex | wc -l) > 0 ))
then
    systemctl stop mysql.service
    if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $servicex | wc -l) > 0 ))
    then
       echo "Error stopping the service"
    else
       echo "Service stopped"
    fi
else
    systemctl start mysql.service
    if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $servicex | wc -l) > 0 ))
    then
        echo "Service started"
    else
        echo "Error starting service"
    fi
fi
```

I don't know if this is possible but can we also include password in the script to avoid password prompt for systemctl ?

Comment: Why not enable them to start at startup? `is obviously not working` Is there a syntax error? What is "not working"? `check if a service is stopped and start the service if yes, otherwise it should stop the service` I do not follow, so it should toggle the service?

Comment: Yes, it should toggle the service. Why not enable at startup: Because I want to run the services when required and stop them when not in use.

Comment: This forum doesn't exist to provide people with code for free, it exists to help people with their code, so I removed "Please provide..." from your subject line as that was guaranteed to get your question closed. See [ask]. If you want someone to write code for you, you can hire contractors at codementor.io, upwork.com, etc,

Comment: Also, please do what the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.". Not doing that and posting a script full of errors that shellcheck would catch as you currently have is another thing that's going to get your question downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine and do what you expect, but starting and stopping services in Linux requires root privilege.

You can use `sudo` or `su` commands to run your script as root, which will also ask you for the root password.

If you want to run your script as root without typing password every time, you can modify your sudoers file to allow your user to do that.

You can use `usermod` command to add a user to the sudo group

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo username
```

**You should be careful when adding a user to the sudoers file or group, because this gives the user the ability to run commands as root.**

Also please share the error message that you received so I can help you better.